# glimagesink render-rectangle can not set in code

Tags: gstreamer

I try to the   gst-launch-1.0  filesrc location=/mnt/baita.jpg !decodebin  ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! imagefreeze ! glimagesink render-rectangle="<0,0,1920,1080>" and  it is Ok!

but i want to put it in codes and i cannot find the format about  the   render-rectangle  parameter  in the c language。so  if i want to put  it  in c  language,how i  should  use it.Thank you very much !

```
                                                                                jih488
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs for `glimagesink` at https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/opengl/glimagesinkelement.html?gi-language=c#glimagesinkelement:render-rectangle reveal that it takes a `GstValueArray` argument.

See https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstvalue.html?gi-language=c#GstValueArray for details and functions to create such an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Florian's suggestion to do it with `g_object_set()` and a `GstValueArray`, but you can even do it more cleanly.

The "render-rectangle" property of glimagesink comes from the fact that it implements the interface [`GstVideoOverlay`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video/gstvideooverlay.html?gi-language=c). So if you want to set this directly, you can use [`gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle()`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video/gstvideooverlay.html?gi-language=c#gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle).